# Extracting a number of strings from an array using Regex

Tags: arrays, regex, vb.net

Trying to find most efficient way to do this and was wondering if regular expressions can be helpful in this case.

I am looping through an array of strings untill I find a string that begins with or contains the following pattern: abc 1234. So far I took care of 2 formats - one white space and 2 whitespace. Although there might be more white spaces in some cases.

Then I enter while loop that should loop through and process each line untill it finds another pattern that also startes with "abc" but is followed by a number other than 1234.

```
If MyArray(i).ToString(0.ToLower().StartsWith("abc 1234") or If MyArray(i).ToString(0.ToLower().StartsWith("abc  1234")

    While Not MyArray(i).ToString().ToLower().StartsWith("abc")

        ''process line here

            i+=1
        End while
end if
```

The thing is that the array contains a bunch of lines staring with "abc 1234" so I never know when to exit untill I encounter another "abc" pattern but with a different number. I do not want to exit the while loop if another "abc 1234" pattern is encountered, so using "abc" in the while loop condition will not suffice

Can anyone help?

I thought of using a function in my while loop condition i.e.

```
Function CheckForEnd(ByVal input As String, ByVal pattern As String) As Boolean
     Dim result As Boolean = False
     If Regex.Split(pattern, "[ ]{1,}").Length = 2 Then
        If Regex.Split(input, "[ ]{1,}").Length > 2 Then
            If Regex.Split(input, "[ ]{1,}")(0).Trim().Equals(Regex.Split(pattern, "[ ]{1,}")(0).Trim()) Then
                If Regex.Split(input, "[ ]{1,}")(1).Trim().Equals(Regex.Split(pattern, "[ ]{1,}")(1).Trim()) Then
                    result = True
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If

    Return result
End Function
```

So my while loop looks like this:

```
While Not CheckForEnd(MyArray(I),"abc 1234")
    ''my code here

   I+=1
End While
```

But I am not sure if that's the most efficient way to do this. Please advice

Here is an example:

"This is a test string."

"This is another test string"

"abc 1234 (100-00)"

"This is another sentence"

"this is a sequence of numbers: 34566900"

"abc  1234 (300-01)"

"More unrelated stuff...."

"abc 7890 (500-01) test"

"more stuff..."

"another string"

So if above is my array of strings (to be clear, each line is a separate array subscript), then I need the following part extracted:

"abc 1234 (100-00)"

"This is another sentence"

"this is a sequence of numbers: 34566900"

"abc  1234 (300-01)"

"More unrelated stuff...."

So I loop through it, after I encounter first abc 123 and the function helps me check each line for occurrence of next abc that is followed by number other than 1234.

Comment: [txt2re](http://txt2re.com/) is pretty helpful for this.

Comment: Could you please clarify how it can be utilized in my particular case?

Answer (score -1):

In the below code `CheckForEnd` returns `True` if a combination other than `1234` is used with `abc`.

Regular Expressions require access to the `RegularExpressions` namespace, thus you'll have to do a `Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions` also.

```
Sub exampleSubroutine()
    [.declare MyArray here.]
    Dim i As Integer = 0

    While Not CheckForEnd(MyArray(i))
        i += 1
        If (MyArray.Count() = i) Then 'Stop a crash if we reach the end of the array.
            Exit While
        End If
    End While

    ProcessMatch(MyArray(i))

End Sub

Sub ProcessMatch(ByVal match As String)
    [.process matched line here.]
End Sub

Function CheckForEnd(ByVal input As String) As Boolean
    Dim re1 As String = "(.*?)^((?!abc 1234).)*$(.*?)"

    Dim r As Regex = New Regex(re1, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase Or RegexOptions.Singleline)
    Dim m As Match = r.Match(input)
    If (m.Success) Then
        Dim word1 = m.Groups(1)
        Dim ws1 = m.Groups(2)
        Dim d1 = m.Groups(3)
        Return True
    End If
    Return False
End Function
```

Comment: I tried the function as follows, passing "abc 1234" in as an argument and it returned true on a string that does not have anything remotely like abc 1234


        Dim re1 As String = "^((?!" & pattern & ").)*$"

I also tested the function with abc 1234 hardcoded and also it returned true on a string that did not contain the target value. The word1 was assigned a dot (.)

Comment: @ElenaDBA Please could you give an example of your array in your question. I tested the code and it works in the situation you describe, and it certainly will *not* return a dot for `word1` ***unless your array has a value with a dot instead of `abc`.***

Comment: the particular value in the array just contained a regular sentence with a dot at the end. Not a single digit and not a single "abc" combo

Comment: @ElenaDBA ***That's not what you asked in your question.*** Please clarify what you actually want here.

Comment: I need to check if the line contains "abc" followed by the number other than "1234". But my array contains different lines with or without abc. Some do, and some don't

Comment: btw, code I posed works. I just wanted to see if that can be done more efficiently using regex

Comment: @ElenaDBA Try the regex modification I just edited. As I asked before, please give a *complete* example of the sentence with `abc` in it. Without it, it is not possible to create a regex pattern for your use-case. As I said try out [txt2re](http://txt2re.com/).

Comment: I just added an example to the question